# Botframework Create Directline get token from server

Tags: reactjs, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I saved the token from createdirectline first time it was initialized to the server. But whenever I get the token from the server and used it, it will not use that token instead it will create a new one.

```js
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const temp = async () => {
      if (Object.entries(directline).length === 0) {
          if(await props.chatBotData!.tokenFromDb){
            setDirectline(createDirectLine({ token: props.chatBotData.tokenFromDb.toString() }));
          }else {
            setDirectline(createDirectLine({ token: DIRECTLINE_SECRET }));
          }
 
      }
    };
    temp();
  }, [directline,props.chatBotData]);
```

```js
  const [directline, setDirectline]: any = useState({});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to save the Direct Line `secret` server-side so it is inaccessible, not the token. The `secret` is used when making a call to `/directline/tokens/generate` or `/directline/conversations` in order to retrieve a token (and `conversationId`, if the latter endpoint). (Reference [Connect a bot to Direct Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-directline?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) and [Generate a Direct Line token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#generate-token).)

In short, this is the flow your site should follow:

1. Web site with Web Chat loads.
2. As Web Chat instantiates, an API call is made to your "token" server (i.e. `https://.../gettoken`.
3. When the "token" server token API is called, it makes a call to `/directline/tokens/generate` passing the `secret` which then returns the `token`.
4. The token is returned back to your calling web site which then passes it for use in `createDirectLine()`.

It's important to note that tokens are only good for 30 mins, at the time of this writing, before they expire. If you are expecting a conversation to last longer than 30 mins, then you will need to perform a similar process to exchange the token for a refreshed token beforehand.

Hope of help!

Comment: So dumb of me that I thought the generated conversation token should be saved to the server. Yea, thanks for this it makes sense now. Just read the docs you linked and it has a refresh token.

Comment: Is there a way to set the expiration of the token from the refreshed one?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The expiration is baked into the token by the service.